# Why was the letter z chosen in z-scores?

Tags: normal-distribution, terminology, z-score

Why was the letter *z* chosen in the name of a z-score *= (data value minus mean) / standard deviation* and not any other letter?

This might be related to the same letter *z* being frequently used for the Normal distribution, but, again, I have no idea why the letter *z* was chosen here. Does it stand for anything?

Comment: The connection with the frequent use of $Z$ for normal random variables is clear. Then the question becomes, why the use of $Z$ for normal random variables.

Comment: @Bruce that Z is heavily used for standard normals is clear but I don't see it used all that much for general normals (less commonly than X or Y would be, I think) -- and the connection between z-scores and standard normals would seem to be relevant. Perhaps you intended to refer to standard normals though.

Comment: @Glen: Meant to say "standard normal" but obviously didn't. Googled this. Finally on p4 I found  [this pg](https://www.animatedsoftware.com/statglos/sgzscore.htm), which mentions z-scores and standard normal in suitably close proximity--3rd paragraph.